# remoteConfig().getAll() return undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(this._values)')

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-remote-config

```
import remoteConfig from '@react-native-firebase/remote-config';

useEffect(() => {
getConfig()
.then(res => console.log(res)
.catch(err => console.log(err.message))
}, [])

const getConfig = async () => {
const firebase = await remoteConfig().getAll();
return firebase
}
```

It return undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(this._values)')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to [fetchAndActivate](https://rnfirebase.io/remote-config/usage#fetch--activate) the remote config before you can use it.
I tested it with your code and it worked afterward

Comment: How I will fetchAndActivate because I have to only get data from remote config

Comment: you need to set default values as well in case your service cannot reach firebase. check the documentation step by step here, it's pretty straightforward: https://rnfirebase.io/remote-config/usage

Comment: Thanks I have resolved by fetchAndActivate on startup of app

Comment: Glad to hear that I could help you. I would appreciate it if you could accept and upvote my answer. Thanks

Comment: I want to accept but no option is here for approved

Comment: No problem. On the left side of my answer, you should see a tick that is grayed out. Right below the Arrow Up/Down and the Count of upvotes. To accept an answer press the tick and upvote. 
Accepting answers does not only help me a little but also other users who might stumble across the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function getDefaultValueFromFirebaseRemoteConfig() {
  try {
    await remoteConfig().fetchAndActivate();
    const data : FirebaseRemoteConfigTypes.ConfigValue = await remoteConfig().getVaue('${key}');
    return (JSON.parse(data.asString()));
   } catch(error) {
    return {live_version: [""]};
   }
}
```